# Processing/Transposing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, crosstab

I got the following pandas dataframe:

```
Id    Category
1     type 2
1     type 3
1     type 2
2     type 1
2     type 2
```

I need to process and transpose the above data frame to:

```
Id Category_type_1 Category_type_2 Category_type_3
1          0               2              1
2          1               1              0
```

Appreciate if anyone could shows the easiest way to code this in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd `groupby` and use `size`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your solution is fastest ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for their solutions! it seems that this answer is the easiest..  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Category'])
Out: 
Category  type 1  type 2  type 3
Id                              
1              0       2       1
2              1       1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
Category  type 1  type 2  type 3
Id                              
1              0       2       1
2              1       1       0
```

**Timings**:

`Small DataFrame - len(df)=5`:

```
In [63]: %timeit df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().unstack().fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit (df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.77 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Category'])
100 loops, best of 3: 4.82 ms per loop
```

`Large DataFrame - len(df)=5k`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [59]: %timeit df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().unstack().fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop

In [60]: %timeit (df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.64 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Category'])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.46 ms per loop
```

`Very large DataFrame - len(df)=5m`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [55]: %timeit df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().unstack().fillna(0)
1 loop, best of 3: 514 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit (df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='Category', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
1 loop, best of 3: 907 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit pd.crosstab(df['Id'], df['Category'])
1 loop, best of 3: 822 ms per loop
```