# How to partially transpose pandas a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821985/processing-transposing-pandas-dataframe). I'd like to partially transpose a pandas dataframe. I got my hands on a dataframe looking similar to the following:

```
data = [{"Student" : "john", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Plan' , "2009" : 100, "2010" : 100},
            {"Student" : "john", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Actual' ,"2009" : 80, "2010" : 100}, 
            {"Student" : "john", "Subject" : 'Math' , 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Delta' ,"2009" : -20, "2010" : 0},
            {"Student" : "lisa", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Plan' ,"2009" : 80, "2010" : 100},
            {"Student" : "lisa", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Actual' ,"2009" : 75, "2010" : 100},
            {"Student" : "lisa", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Plan_Actual_Delta' : 'Delta' ,"2009" : -5, "2010" : 0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It shows students and their planned and actual performance (and the delta) for a given subject in a given year. The years are columns in this example. And whether the row shows the planned, actual or the delta of the students performance is given in the rows.

I'd like to transform it in a way that plan, actual and delta become columns. 
My goal is hence the following strucuture:

```
data = [{"Student" : "john", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Year': '2009', 'Plan':100, 'Actual':80, 'Delta': -20},
       {"Student" : "john", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Year': '2010', 'Plan':100, 'Actual':100, 'Delta': 0},
        {"Student" : "lisa", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Year': '2009', 'Plan':80, 'Actual':75, 'Delta': -5},
       {"Student" : "lisa", "Subject" : 'Math', 'Year': '2010', 'Plan':100, 'Actual':100, 'Delta': 0}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How would you do that? Thanks in advance /R

Comment: You are looking for pivot table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by third level:

```
df = (df.set_index(['Student','Subject','Plan_Actual_Delta'])
        .rename_axis('Year', axis=1)
        .stack()
        .unstack(2)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  Student Subject  Year  Actual  Delta  Plan
0    john    Math  2009      80    -20   100
1    john    Math  2010     100      0   100
2    lisa    Math  2009      75     -5    80
3    lisa    Math  2010     100      0   100
```

Another solution, if not working first with possible aggregation with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = (df.melt(['Student','Subject','Plan_Actual_Delta'], var_name='Year')
        .pivot_table(index=['Student','Subject','Year'], 
                     columns='Plan_Actual_Delta',
                     values='value',
                     aggfunc='mean')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
print (df)
  Student Subject  Year  Actual  Delta  Plan
0    john    Math  2009      80    -20   100
1    john    Math  2010     100      0   100
2    lisa    Math  2009      75     -5    80
3    lisa    Math  2010     100      0   100
```